# PowerPoint - How to see TOTAL run time after creating slide show

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, timing

I have already created a slide show using the AUTOMATIONS tab and the `Advance Slide Automatically After ----` function where I have manually entered the runtime of each individual slide until my Slide Show was complete.  I now have a finished Show, but I want to determine its TOTAL Running Time.  I would think the program would be able to give this information without running a Rehearsal, but I tried the Rehearsal function and found that will not accomplish this either.

How can I see the total run time?

Answer (score 4):

I recently had the same need and having been unable to find a simple solution, I added a feature to a free add-in that I created for PowerPoint power users called [BrightSlide](https://brightcarbon.com/brightslide). It adds the required info to the **Timing** group of the **Transitions** tab. Here's a couple of screenshots of the feature in action:

[image: Modified Timing group in the Transitions tab of PowerPoint]

When clicking the **Detail** button (old screenshot from former product):

[image]

To access the feature in BrightSlide, click the **BrightSlide** tab followed by **Settings & Help** / **Settings** / **Ribbon Setup** and check **Legacy Tools**. You'll then see a new Legacy Tools drop down in the BrightSlide ribbon in which you can activate the **Timing Pro** tools. They will then appear in the PowerPoint **Transitions** tab.

Comment: It's worth nothing that this is commercial software.

Comment: @LarsViklund And it looks like you can no longer buy it.  (Too bad, too, because I might have, depending on price.)

Comment: Looks like this time-tracking component is called "TalkTime" and offered for free here: http://youpresent.co.uk/free-stuff/talktime-powerpoint/. For the timings of individual slides, you can also use PPT's integrated rehearsal feature, as suggested in this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31803985/3017719.

Comment: Yep, that's a [different] free add-in to use when practising your presentation and gives you the total present (TalkTime) per slide/section/presentation that you set, based on the time you spend on the slide in slide show mode (hence different from the above which uses PowerPoint animation times). I developed TalkTime for Nolan Haims Creative: https://presentyourstory.com/talktime-free-presentation-time-management-add-powerpoint/

Comment: @LarsViklund and BobBrown - regarding the original feature, it's still available, and it's now free. It's part of a brand new add-in that I developed for BrightCarbon and it's called BrightSlide. You can get it here: https://www.brightcarbon.com/brightslide/ I'll update the original [old] post accordingly.

Comment: @BobBrown thanks for bringing that to my attention :-)

Comment: I forgot to mention that to get the Timing Pro tools in BrightSlide, you need to enable the Legacy Tools in Settings & Help / Settings / Ribbon Setup and then activate Timing Pro in the Legacy Tools drop down that appears in the ribbon.

Comment: Great tool! Please keep supporting and developing it.

Answer (score 3):

To know the total time of a presentation with recorded timing, go to the `Slide Show` menu, and select `Record from current slide` as follows

[image]

The following recording window will open with the total time of the presentation (in this case 16m 15s) in the bottom left, as I indicated with the red arrow (Note: this will **not** start the recording until you press the red button `Record`)

[image]

I tested this on the current (2021) latest PowerPoint for Office 365 (v16.0)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution I found by a lot of trial and error. All you need to do is click on "Rehearse Timing" again, then move the bar on the bottom of the screen until you see the last slide. Click on that slide, and then end the show. It will show you the original timing you did. Then click yes or no, it doesn't matter, as it will record the same times.

Answer (score -1):

This is not directly an answer to the OP's question about seeing the total time, but on a similar quest I've found this useful: If you go to the "Slide Sorter", either from the View ribbon or from the "Slide Sorter" button in the bottom line of the window, you'll see an overview of your slides along with the time for each slide.

This page doesn't give you the total time of all the slides, but it does tell you in a glance how long each of the slides takes, which helped me.

[image: Slide sorter View]

(My actual slides contain timing information for each and every slide, but the screenshot here only shows `00:05` for some slides; I don't know why... Works great for me)

Comment: This number underneath isn't the "Duration" value, it's the "Advance Slide After" value

Answer (score -1):

I just export the pptx to video, then look at the total video time . . .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to Super User!  Your answer is not in line with the question which is soliciting solutions in PowerPoint.    Please avoid answering old questions that have answers unless you have something significant to add.

Answer (score -2):

From this [Office support article](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/Rehearse-and-time-the-delivery-of-a-presentation-8424270a-d865-4aed-a321-1d2dd656381a):

> On the Slide Show tab, in the Set Up group, click Rehearse Timings.
>
> The Rehearsal toolbar appears and the Slide Time box begins timing the presentation.
>
> [image]
>
> 1. Next (advance to next slide)
> 2. Pausecallout
> 3. Slide Time callout
> 4. Repeat
> 5. Total presentation time
>
> While timing your presentation, do one or more of the following on the Rehearsal toolbar:
>
> - To move to the next slide, click Next.
> - To temporarily stop recording the time, click Pause.
> - To restart recording the time after pausing, click Pause.
> - To set an exact length of time for a slide to appear, type the length of time in the Slide Time book.
> - To restart recording the time for the current slide, click Repeat.
>
> After you set the time for the last slide, a message box displays the
>   total time for the presentation and prompts you to do one of the
>   following:
>
> - To keep the recorded slide timings, click Yes.
> - To discard the recorded slide timings, click No.
>
> Slide Sorter view appears and displays the time of each slide in your
>   presentation.

Comment: Please don't just copy-paste content, but 1) make sure it looks like it should and don't just press `Ctrl-V` and be done with it 2) use blockquote formatting to highlight the parts that you did not write. This is also important.